# How to Know What Filesystem External Harddrive is Using

Tags: debian, filesystems, hard-disk, external-hdd

How can I tell what file system an external hard drive has using Debian?

I have opened it via the GUI, but there is nothing listed for 'filesystem type'

[image: no filesystem]

Comment: Use [gparted](http://gparted.sourceforge.net).

Comment: You can use `mount` command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unsure why I am being downvoted, but I was able to find the information using:

`fdisk -l`, which returns:

```
Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1        2048 1953521663 1953519616 931.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

Comment: This command shows the **partition type**, not the **filesystem** on it.

Answer (score 3):

The best option I have seen is [lsblk](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsblk.8.html)'s file system option:

```
lsblk -f
```

This will print out all block devices (mounted or not) and their file system's.

Answer (score 0):

`findmnt -o source,fstype`

`cat /proc/mounts`

`blkid`

Comment: What is the difference between `cat /proc/mounts` and `mount` command?